# Penrose process and the change in irreducible mass

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric

This is a minor confusion. In various lectures notes, for example by  Carrol or by Strominger, when discussing the Penrose process of extracting energy from the Kerr black hole, they will exploit the inequality
$$
- p \cdot (\partial_t + \Omega_H \partial_\varphi) > 0 \ .
$$
where $p$ is the particle that is sacrificed (and enters the outer horizon) to kick the hero out of the ergosphere. Naively I would think that this equality is a strict one unless there is no particle (and no Penrose process) at all.

However, when the authors discuss the change in $M_\text{irr}$, they will write
$$
\delta M_\text{irr} \ge 0 \ ,
$$
with a potential **equal sign**.

I wonder if this **equal sign** refers to an empty Penrose progress, or if it refers to **actual Penrose progress** that keeps the $M_\text{irr}$ unchanged (and what is such process if it exists)?

Comment: @A.V.S. Ah right, bad typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **another possibility** (apart from the "empty" Penrose process you mentioned in which there is no particle) that after going inside the ergosphere the particle **comes outside without any change** (since the ergosphere is outside the outer event horizon). That is it will not divide into two particles. In this case also $M_\text{irr}$ is constant.

It is **not possible** that the initial particle divides into 2 particles and **one particle goes into the outer event horizon** and other comes out with more energy and **still** $M_\text{irr}$ **is constant**. The reason is that since entropy $dS=\frac{dA}{4}\propto dM_\text{irr}$ and since the process is **irreversible** (as one particle goes into the outer event horizon and it can never return) we can say that $dS>0\Rightarrow dM_\text{irr}>0$.

Comment: I personally would classify such "no-divide-process" as an empty Penrose process as well, but in any case I agree that it doesn't affect $M_\text{irr}$